# ACF: Only get first row of a Repeater Field

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater filed called "images" and inside it I have a sub_filed called "image".

How can I get only the first row value?

Here is my code

```
<?php if( have_rows('images') ): ?>
<?php
$active = 'active';
while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row();
$image = get_sub_field('image');
if($image == "" ) continue;
?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/files/images/<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
<?php $active = '';
endwhile;
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I tried

```
<?php if( have_rows('images') ): ?>
<?php
 $active = 'active';
 while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row();
 $image = get_sub_field('image');
 if($image == "" ) continue;
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/files/images/<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
<?php break;
 <?php $active = '';
 endwhile;
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code

```
<?php if( have_rows('images') ): ?>
    <?php
            $active = 'active';

            while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row();
            
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                    
                    if ($image !== '') {
    ?>
                                 <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri(). '/files/images/'. $image); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
                                <?php $active = ''; ?>
    <?php        
                    }
                    
                    break;

            endwhile;
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

"While" is executed at least 1 time and therefore you can put "break" at the end.

Also need to use the function [esc_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) for the escaping url